# Perl recursive copy and move functions

Tags: performance, recursion, file-system, perl, modules

I know a module like this already exists on CPAN, but I wanted to write my own simplified version that accepts wildcards in the input.

I don't write many Perl modules so I figured I would post the code here and see if anyone could give me advice on how to make this code more efficient or user friendly.

*I also included some POD documentation so you can use perldoc for usage information.*

**Please let me know what you think and leave some feedback on how this code could be improved!**

```
package File::Copy::Recursive;

# Use statements
use File::Basename;
use File::Copy;
use File::Path qw(make_path remove_tree);
use strict;
use warnings;

# Link the version number with CVS
our ($VERSION) = (q$Revision: 1.1 $ =~ m{([0-9.]+)});

# Exporter
require Exporter;
our @ISA = qw(
    Exporter
);

# Declare exportable routines
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(
    recursive_copy rcopy
    recursive_move rmove
);

# Aliases to subroutines
sub rcopy { recursive_copy(@_); }
sub rmove { recursive_move(@_); }

# Recursive copy function
sub recursive_copy {
    my ($source, $destination) = @_;
    for my $path (glob $source) {
        if (-d $path) {
            make_path($destination.'/'.basename($path));
            recursive_copy($path.'/*', $destination.'/'.basename($path));
        }
        else {
            copy($path, $destination);
        }
    }
}

# Recursive move function
sub recursive_move {
    my ($source, $destination) = @_;
    for my $path (glob $source) {
        if (-d $path) {
            make_path($destination.'/'.basename($path));
            recursive_move($path.'/*', $destination.'/'.basename($path));
            remove_tree($path);
        }
        else {
            move($path, $destination);
        }
    }
}

1;

__END__

=head1 NAME

File::Copy::Recursive - Recursive copy and move functions.

=head1 VERSION

$Revision: 1.1 $

=head1 SYNOPSIS

  use File::Copy::Recursive;

  # Recursively copy a directory
  recursive_copy('input', 'output');

  # Recursively copy all contents of a directory
  recursive_copy('input/*', 'output');

  # Recursively move a directory
  recursive_move('input', 'output');

  # Recursively move all contents of a directory
  recursive_move('input/*', 'output');

=head1 DESCRIPTION

File::Copy::Recursive is designed to provide simple functions to recursively copy and move files.
These functions will accept wildcards (*) in the input.

=head1 SUBROUTINES/METHODS

=over

=item C<recursive_copy> or C<rcopy>

Recursive copy function.

  # Recursively copy a directory
  recursive_copy('input', 'output');

  # Recursively copy all contents of a directory
  recursive_copy('input/*', 'output');

=item C<recursive_move> or <rmove>

Recursive move function.

  # Recursively move a directory
  recursive_move('input', 'output');

  # Recursively move all contents of a directory
  recursive_move('input/*', 'output');

=back
```

Comment: Doesn't the Unix "mv" command already do recursive move? Or is this for a platform which may not have a recursive version of mv/rename? I take it you need a pure Perl solution, so no using "find", for example?

Comment: Yes Unix does have a recursive move but I am running this on Windows.  I am basically trying to emulate the functionality of the Unix `mv`/`cp` functions with the `-r` recursive flag set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got a security vulnerability here just waiting to be exploited based on the fact you use the same interface for "The human" and "The Filesystem".

All you need is for somebody to create a file with:

```
open my $fh, '>', 'path/*'
```

And that will get glob-expansion during traversal.

Which means you **DON'T** want to use glob at a level other than the user-facing function call for the sake of convenience.

The user facing function should probably use use [`Text::Glob::glob_to_regex`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Glob#Routines) so you can generate a "match rule" and re-use it for subsequent operations,
instead of relying on `glob` to return a list of files.

When the function calls itself, it should use `opendir` + `readdir` which is not subject to glob expansion.

Your code also assumes a *lot* about OS File Path semantics.

So for Filesystem manipulation, I would probably suggest lots of [`File::Spec`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Spec) or [`Path::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny), as they're far more battle tested against Path handling, and the later provides a few helper functions that will make tree traversal and iteration much more obvious. ( And importantly, much safer )

As for the Exporter call, this style is more recommended:

```
use Exporter 5.57 qw( import );
```

This simply creates the `import` sub on your package instead of fussing with `@ISA` and thus eliminates the need for `Exporter` to be part of your inheritance tree.

If you want to support versions of `Exporter` older that 5.57, this is equally effective and can be expected to work on a stock 5.6 perl:

```
use Exporter ();
*import = \&Exporter::import;
```

### Example

The following code constructs a diabolical directory that will result in graph traversal happening not once, but several times.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

## Creating an example "Evil" directory to traverse.

use Test::TempDir::Tiny qw( tempdir );
use Path::Tiny qw( path );

my $dir = tempdir();

# Problem directories
path( $dir, "evil/*" )->mkpath;
path( $dir, "evil/*/starfile" )->touch;
path( $dir, "evil/**" )->mkpath;
path( $dir, "evil/**/doublestarfile" )->touch;


# Normal Files
path( $dir, "evil/child/deep" )->mkpath;

path( $dir, "evil/child" )->mkpath;
path( $dir, "evil/child/a" )->touch;
path( $dir, "evil/child/b" )->touch;
path( $dir, "evil/child/deep/a" )->touch;
path( $dir, "evil/child/deep/b" )->touch;

## Evil directory now constructed, emulated simplified recursion
## using glob 

our $DEPTH = 0;
our $PAD   = '';

sub list_files_recursively {
  my ( $path ) = @_;
  STDERR->print("${PAD}?: $path\n");
  local $DEPTH = $DEPTH + 1;
  local $PAD   = ' ' x $DEPTH;
  my @out;
  ###### DONT DO THIS ######
  for my $leaf ( glob $path ) {
  ###### DONT DO THIS ######
    if ( -d $leaf ) {
      STDERR->print("${PAD}d: $leaf\n");
      push @out, list_files_recursively( $leaf . '/*' );
    }
    else {
      STDERR->print("${PAD}f: $leaf\n");
      push @out, $leaf;
    }
  }
  return @out;
}

for my $entry ( list_files_recursively( "$dir/*" ) ) {
  print $entry . "\n";
}

print "Expected layout:\n";
system("find",$dir,"-type", "f" );
```

Executing this code will reveal list_files_recursively "visits" the same files multiple times.

Full output [here omitted for brevity](https://gist.github.com/kentfredric/5da23907ee26861c2f65d6e244773a2f)

The most important part is to note what happens when it tries to list the children of the directory called `**`

```
  d: /tmp/7LYkL6zdrB/test_pl/default_1/evil/**
  ?: /tmp/7LYkL6zdrB/test_pl/default_1/evil/**/*
   f: /tmp/7LYkL6zdrB/test_pl/default_1/evil/**/doublestarfile
   f: /tmp/7LYkL6zdrB/test_pl/default_1/evil/*/starfile
   f: /tmp/7LYkL6zdrB/test_pl/default_1/evil/child/a
   f: /tmp/7LYkL6zdrB/test_pl/default_1/evil/child/b
   d: /tmp/7LYkL6zdrB/test_pl/default_1/evil/child/deep
```

Yes, that's thinking "Hey, it looks like 'child/deep' is a child of `**`".

Which it really really isn't.

And there are probably plenty more glob rules that can be exploited here, `*` is just the most dangerous.

For instance, glob interprets spaces as token delimiters, so glob "a b"  -> 2 entries, not 1.

Comment: Couldn't someone just say `open my $fh, '>', 'path/*' ` regardless of whether they're using this module or not?

Comment: That's not the problem. The problem is when the authors code *finds* a file that was created that way, and passes said filename into `glob`. 

`my $filename = "path/*" # from the filesystem
for my $filename ( glob $filename ) {`  # Expanded here even though it wasn't a user parameter

Comment: I can try to write an example test case using your code if it helps understand, but it requires a bit of effort.

Comment: So basically the problem can occur if the file name itself contains an asterisk?  Is that even possible?  If it is that is good to know!

Comment: The point is "You're using glob for 2 different things".  The first is for asking the user for a list of glob expressions which can map to multiple files. The second is where you use it internally as a cheat for directory iteration.  The problem is the latter.  Because filenames can contain arbitrary characters that are part of the glob syntax, any character literals in the literal filename that are also globs result in "glob expansion", so instead of "copying/moving file X", you're "copying/moving file(s)  based on the expansion of the filename X".

Comment: Which basically means, arbitrary files lying on your file system can *control* the behaviour of future moves/copies in arbitrary ways. 

And you **really** don't want that.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense now.  I will definitely have to change that!

Comment: I've added an example that demonstrates the kind of problem this creates, hopefully, to your satisfaction. =)

Comment: What about using `use parent 'Exporter';`?  Then all I need to do is add things to `@EXPORT_OK` and I'm done.  Is there something wrong with that approach?

Comment: It makes your class inherit from Exporter, which is not actually a useful thing to do, typically. Especially if all you're wanting is the 'import', exporter will give you a bunch of methods you didn't ask for in your inheritance, and leads to a bunch of inheritance things all over the place that aren't useful.
I'm basically doing this, but with a wider support range: https://metacpan.org/pod/Exporter#Exporting-Without-Inheriting-from-Exporter

Comment: Install (my module) https://metacpan.org/pod/App::Isa::Splain and then run `isa-splain File::Copy::Recursive` to see the difference. ( Assuming its in your @INC somewhere )

Comment: Would probably also be worth naming it something different to avoid confusion with https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Copy::Recursive

Comment: Yes I agree, I moved it into a subfolder containing other custom modules and renamed it to avoid naming conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

If `make_path` fails, then statements are still attempted. Perhaps ensure path creation succeeds, quickly failing rather than continuing to attempt I/O.

`recursive_copy`, `recursive_move` arguments are the same in the two `sub`. Could consolidate those values, storing them in temporary variables used by either. String literals, concatenation would instead be in only one line of code.

Could consolidate the two `sub` into one with the goal of reducing duplicate code, loop logic. Could use an argument providing the move, copy option, perhaps with copy as a reasonable default. Suggest ternary conditionals based on this argument or flag.